# copying postgreSQL database, table with same number of rows, but different table size

Tags: postgresql, greenplum, pg-dump

I dumped the database with:

```
pg_dump dsmartgpp -f /data1/master/backup/db.sql
```

and I copied the database with

```
nohup psql -h gpnm1 -d dsmartgpp_1 -U gpadmin < /data1/master/backup/db.sql
```

the log information showed some errors about the function and datatype of postgis, such as

> ALTER FUNCTION
> ERROR:  function "gidx_out" already exists with same argument types.

> ALTER FUNCTION
> ERROR:  type "gidx" already exists

some tables between the two database have the same number or records, but about 1MB difference in size.

Comment: a 1mb difference sounds pretty decent to me. Have you tried to vacuum before creating the backup?

Answer (score 2):

That is as expected. Restoring a `pg_dump` creates a *logical* copy of the database. In particular, the copy won't be bloated (don't worry – a bit of bloat is healthy).

Comment: *"don't worry – a bit of bloat is healthy"* sounds like something that could be printed on dbas t-shirts ;) +1

Comment: yes! but totally, as there are many tables in the database, the diff is huge( 2-3GB).

Comment: oldDB is 2-3GB bigger than newDB, I'm sure I have vacuumed the oldDB before

Comment: would there be some difference on default size of data type of PG between two version( newDB is 6.11 and oldDB is 4.x)

Comment: Of course, too much bloat is not healthy. So if the new table were 10MB, but the old one 2GB, you have a problem. `VACUUM` won't reorganize a table, but `VACUUM (FULL)` will get rid of bloat.

Comment: The PostGIS data types in Greenplum should not be different in 4.x and 6.x.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid these errors, create the new database (*dsmartgpp_1*) with *template0* as template (empty database). You seem to have PostGIS installed in *template1*, which gets copied into every new database. Or you installed PostGIS in your new database, before importing the dump.

Either way, create the empty database (*dsmartgpp_1*) and let the dump install the PostGIS functions.

Oh, one more thing, you can use "`-f /data1/master/backup/db.sql`" instead of the "`<`" redirect.

If you want to be super careful, also add "`-v ON_ERROR_STOP=1`". This will stop at the first error.

Comment: I tried to create the new database with template0, however, as the new database and the old one are in different clusters with different versions of PostGIS (2.5/new and 2.0/old), when i was going to let the dump install the PostGIS functions in the new database, It would show errors: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.0": No such file or directory

Comment: Ah well, in this case you have manual work in front of you. The easiest one would be to install the new system with the old PostGIS version, install the schema and then upgrade PostGIS.

Comment: If that does not work, install PostGIS in the database, and remove all mentions of it from the backup. Using the custom format with an index for the backup is useful for this.